# How to adminstrate configuration in node/express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I would like to remove the configuration out of my app.js and split it into severall files:

`/config/app.js` (for the whole `app.configure(function(){});`)

and `/config/view.js` (for the template engine configuration)

Unfortunatly javascript doesn't know any include function and I would like to avoid to write an own.

So what is the best approach do split the configuration from `app.js`?

**config.js**

```
module.exports = function(app, express, passport){
app.configure(function(){
    app.use(express.logger());
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.session({ secret: 'kitty'}));
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view options', { layout: false });
});
};

var config = require('./config/app.js')
var app = module.exports = express.createServer();
```

**app.js**

```
var app = express.createServer();
var config = require('./config/app.js')(app, express, passport);
```

Comment: What do you mean there is no include function? You use `require` and you're there!

Comment: Hi, I updated the Post. This was what I tried first but this doesn't work, I get an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to use `require` incorrectly. Do it like this:

**app.js**

```
var app = express.createServer();
var config = require('./config')(app);
```

**config.js**

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.configure(function () {
        app.use(express.logger());
        /* etc */
    });
};
```

Comment: Hi, I had to overgive the function all dependencies. I have updated my post. This would work now but is not very smart. Is there a way maybe to map all dependencies into an array or an object and than overgive only this one while keeping the short var name of the dependency.

Comment: Actually the only thing you need to pass is `app` object. You can load all other libraries in `config.js` module. There is no way to make this process automatic.